# i = empty how can i solve this?

Tags: excel, vba

```
Dim a As Integer
a = 0



For i = 4 To i + 1

    Set xRange = Sheets("sayfa4").Rows(i)

        For j = 1 To 10

            If Sheets("sayfa4").Cells(i, j) > 0 And Sheets("sayfa4").Cells(i, j) =  Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(xRange) Then
                a = a + 1
                Sheets("sayfa4").Cells(i, j).ClearContents
                
                Sheets("sayfa4").Cells(15 + a, 1) = i
                Sheets("sayfa4").Cells(15 + a, 2) = j
                
            
                  i = j - 1
            End If
            
        Next j
        
            
Next i
```

i don't get any errors or something i just can't execute it nothing happens on excel sheet can you help me guys what is the problem
when i try with F8  it shows "i = empty"
my main problem is declaring the next i actually
when i choose a cell(i,j) and printing the value of it
my next i should be j and after i should start to search min value of j row and it turns out next i

Comment: `For i = 4 To i + 1` -  `i + 1` equals `1`. It is also bad practice to modify `i` within the loop.

Comment: `i + 1` will not change the number of loops.  The second number is set at the point of instantiation.

Comment: it is cause of this stackoverflows format that wasn'a typo :) , well so do you have any suggest what should i do , i am kinda trying to applicate the dijkstra algorithm

Comment: I am not sure, but try a do/while loop instead.

Comment: i saw this but didn't understand one thing

Comment: are you trying to loop unitl last row?

Comment: actually i am trying to loop all rows starting from randomly , i mean  i want that i want to use all valued cells it like if i have 1-2 ,1-5,1-9 i should also declare and print them it is working like , if i do 1-5 , it means i went 1 to 5 and now i am on point 5 so now i will have to do 5-x

Comment: @BigBen has it right. and so is ScottCraner.  The To value of the loop is set at 1 so your loop becomes For i=4 to 1.  As 1 is less then 4 the loop will never execute.

Comment: Another FYI is to avoid `Integer` in VBA and use `Long` instead which is the native 32-bit integer type on all windows machines. `Integer` is actually a 16-bit number that can overflow if it ever goes above 32768.

Comment: well it doesn't go even 10000

Answer (score 0):

I tryed to understand your logic and rewrote the code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Dim a As Integer
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim xRange As Range
    a = 0
    
    i = 4
    For i = 4 To i + 1
    
        Set xRange = Sheets("sayfa4").Rows(i)
    
            For j = 1 To 10
    
                If Sheets("sayfa4").Cells(i, j) > 0 And Sheets("sayfa4").Cells(i, j) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(xRange) Then
                    a = a + 1
                    'Sheets("sayfa4").Cells(i, j).ClearContents
                    
                    Sheets("sayfa4").Cells(15 + a, 1) = i
                    Sheets("sayfa4").Cells(15 + a, 2) = j
                    
                    Exit For
                      'i = j - 1
                End If
                
            Next j
            
                
    Next i

End Sub
```

If you are looking for the minimum value of a selection, this code should solve your issue

Comment: but it depends on  i

Comment: yeah i tried to implement it but it stops when 3th iteration i don't know why

Comment: because for i = 4 to i + 1 means 4 to 5. It runs twice. If you need to run more, you have to calculate the final line (i mean replace i+1 for other number, variable, etc)

Comment: hmm i see thank you btw i will try that , in fact i was kinda hoping that i= j-1 line would help replacing the i's value actually and also i +1'

Comment: do you have any suggestion for how to making when selected cell is (i,j) and at the next iteration making it (j,x)

Comment: You have to understand what you want, then you write the code. I suggest you do loop calculating the variable i = firstRow to lastRow and j = firstColumn to lastColumn. you have the first row, so the las trow could be Sheets("sayfa4").Range("A1048576").end(xlUp).Row

Answer (score 0):

This statement is meaningless

```
For i = 4 To i + 1
```

this is because `i` is uninitialized or zero and so the loop is really `For i=4 to 1` which will be ignored.

If you do not know how many times to iterate use a `Do Loop` instead. Only use `For` for fixed iterations and **do not alter the iteration variable inside the loop**.

If you want to stop the loop use `Exit For`, or `Exit Do` and if you want to end the function or subroutine processing use `Exit Function` or `Exit Sub`.

To skip to the next iteration in VBA you would use an `If` structure, since it does not have a continuation keyword like other languages have. (thanks @BigBen)

Comment: @BigBen You are connect. See edits above.